# Macro to store the length of a paragraph's last line

Tags: formatting

Based on an answer here, I've defined a macro that should store the last line of the current paragraph without producing any output.  But the code below produces the expected result only the first time the macro is used.  Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\setindent{%
    {\abovedisplayshortskip\z@\abovedisplayskip\z@
    \belowdisplayshortskip\z@\belowdisplayskip\z@
$$\global\dimen\@ne\predisplaysize
 \xdef\tmp{%
      \predisplaysize\the\predisplaysize
      \prevgraf\the\prevgraf\relax}%
$$\vskip\dimexpr-\parskip-2\baselineskip\relax}\tmp
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\setindent

\noindent \hskip\dimen\@ne
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\setindent

\noindent \hskip\dimen\@ne
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My example in the answer you refer to (without citing it) is `\lipsum*[1]\parvrulefill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\lipsum` adds a `\par` at the end of the text and if you use `$$` in vertical mode then TeX generates an empty paragraph line with just and `\indent` box and `\parfillskip` glue, so the length of the last line is always `\parindent`.

That's why you should never have a blank line before display math.

If you use `\lipsum*` you get

[image]